# How can I optimize the query that using function in select statement?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

let me show you my code.

THIS is my function
         That return me date time .

```
  ALTER FUNCTION GoldenMemebr(@clubid uniqueidentifier ) returns datetime
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
   as
  begin
 DECLARE @TEMP TABLE 
 (
 TRANSTIME DATETIME,
 TOTSCORE  BIGINT,
 CLUBID uniqueidentifier
 )
INSERT INTO @TEMP (CLUBID,TRANSTIME,TOTSCORE)

 SELECT ClubProfileId, TransactionTimeStamp, 
 SUM(Points) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionTimeStamp) totalamount 
 FROM  
  dbo.CardTransaction CT
 inner join dbo.CardTransactionLog CL 
 on CL.CardTransactionLogId =   CT.CardTransactionLogId
 and ClubProfileId = @clubid

  order by CL.TransactionTimeStamp 

declare @ti datetime
set @ti = 
(
 SELECT top 1 TRANSTIME  
 FROM @TEMP 
WHERE TOTSCORE >= 12000 
order by TRANSTIME asc

)
 return @ti
 end
```

and this is my Query

```
select FirstName,LastName,
SUM(Points) as score,   dbo.GoldenMemebr(cp.ClubProfileId) as ExactTime 
from ClubProfile cp join CardTransaction ct
on ct.ClubProfileId = cp.ClubProfileId
where MembershipType = 1
group by FirstName,LastName,dbo.GoldenMemebr(cp.ClubProfileId)
```

this query take 14 sec for 38 records(it is terrible)

how can i optimized that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not creating and populating a temporary table and removing a useless "ORDER BY" i have tried to improve your function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GoldenMemebr
(
  @clubid uniqueidentifier
) returns datetime
WITH SCHEMABINDING
  as
begin
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    TransactionTimeStamp, 
    SUM(Points) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionTimeStamp) totalamount 
  FROM  
    dbo.CardTransaction CT
  JOIN dbo.CardTransactionLog CL 
  ON
    CL.CardTransactionLogId =   CT.CardTransactionLogId and
    ClubProfileId = @clubid
)
SELECT top 1 @ti = TransactionTimeStamp
FROM CTE
WHERE totalamount >= 12000
ORDER BY totalamount asc

RETURN @ti
end
```

Having index on TransactionTimeStamp and CardTransactionLogId is also likely to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing this function to an inline table valued function instead?

See if this helps point you in a better direction. Please note, you will have to first drop your function because you can't do an alter and change it from a scalar to an iTVF.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION GoldenMemebr(@clubid uniqueidentifier ) returns table
WITH SCHEMABINDING as
    RETURN
    with Totals as
    (
        SELECT TransactionTimeStamp
            , SUM(Points) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionTimeStamp) as totalamount 
        FROM dbo.CardTransaction CT
        inner join dbo.CardTransactionLog CL on CL.CardTransactionLogId = CT.CardTransactionLogId
            and ClubProfileId = @clubid
    )

    select top 1 TransactionTimeStamp
    from Totals
    where totalamount > 12000
    order by CL.TransactionTimeStamp 


    GO

    select FirstName
        , LastName
        , SUM(Points) as score
        , gm.TransactionTimeStamp as ExactTime 
    from ClubProfile cp 
    join CardTransaction ct on ct.ClubProfileId = cp.ClubProfileId
    cross apply dbo.GoldenMember(cp.ClubProfileId) gm
    where MembershipType = 1
    group by FirstName
        , LastName
        , gm.TransactionTimeStamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slow because it is doing [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)(Row By Agonizing Row) operation as the function is called for each frikkin row. Try getting rid of function and wrap the entire logic into a query. This is my try(Untested though)

```
select MIN(TRANSTIME) TransTime, ClubProfileId  into #temp from 
(
 SELECT ClubProfileId, TransactionTimeStamp TransTime, 
 SUM(Points) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionTimeStamp) totalamount 
 FROM  
  dbo.CardTransaction CT
 inner join dbo.CardTransactionLog CL 
 on CL.CardTransactionLogId =   CT.CardTransactionLogId

)A where totalamount >= 12000


create  index ix_id on #temp(ClubProfileId) include (TRANSTIME)

select FirstName
,LastName
,SUM(Points) as score
,t.TransTime ExactTime 
from ClubProfile cp join CardTransaction ct
on ct.ClubProfileId = cp.ClubProfileId
join #temp t on t.ClubProfileId = cp.ClubProfileId
where MembershipType = 1
group by FirstName,LastName,t.TransTime
```

I preferred temp table over a CTE because it offers the flexibility of reuse and that indices can be added on it.